# How to add Hadoop to dependencies via maven?

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-flink

I'm trying to build an apache flink job which has to access files via HDFS. It runs fine locally, but when I submit my job to a flink cluster, I get the error:

`Hadoop is not in the classpath/dependencies.`

I'm using the Maven shade plugin to build my job.jar. The Flink cluster has no Hadoop jars, so I have to add all of them to the job itself.

Locally, I had to add the option in my IDE settings "Add dependencies with "provided" scope to class path to make it work but I have no idea how to do that with maven.

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${dep.flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${dep.flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
...
<build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.maven-compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${project.build.targetJdk}</source>
                    <target>${project.build.targetJdk}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.maven-shade.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.apache.commons.cli</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>org.test.examples.thirdparty.commons_cli</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                            <filters>
                                <!-- Filters out signed files to avoid SecurityException when integrating a signed jar in the resulting jar. -->
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you on YARN read [yarn deployment](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/resource-providers/yarn/).

Make sure that the HADOOP_CLASSPATH environment variable is set up (it can be checked by running `echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH`). If not, set it up using

```
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath`
```

To add maven dependency you can go to [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/) search artifact you want, choose your version and you will have a dependency code on th page to add it in to your `.pom` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

you add it between the tags `<dependencies>` `</dependencies>`

Comment: Why do I need hadoop to run my flink app? From my understanding, I should only need the maven dependency in my job for the connection with HDFS.

I have hadoop installed on one machine while flink runs on another, so I don't have hadoop in my flinkcluster.

> "To add maven dependency you can go to maven repo search artifact you want, choose your version and you will have a dependency code on th page to add it in to your .pom file:"

I have done that but still same error. I tried all kind of hadoop/hdfs/flink-connection dependencies i could find.

Comment: What version of Flink do you use. What you trying to do and how - can help too. I never tried to access HDFS being away from it.  Providing more details can help better understand your problem.

Comment: I run a flink cluster v1.15 on docker. Next to it, I run a Hadoop cluster also with docker. I have a file in my hadoop cluster saved on HDFS. I want to create a flink job that runs on my flink cluster, which reads the file from my HDFS.
When I run my flink locally (via my IDE) it works but when I comile it to a jar and run it on the flink cluster I get this error: Hadoop is not in the classpath/dependencies.

Comment: You should add that info you gave me into your main topic and someone will give you exact answer. I think the main problem with your Flink Standalone cluster in Docker that doesn't know anything about existence of your HDFS cluster and you should provide `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` of HDFS container to your Flink container...

Comment: @nanobot HDFS is meant for large files. Unless you are trying to emulate a production environment, you don't really need HDFS namenode/datanode docker containers... Just mount your data files directly in the Flink containers to read/process there

Comment: Bumping this a bit I came into the same issue and was wondering... What do you do when you've got to point to an external HDFS? With this I mean, I've got Hadoop in my Docker image but I require different core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml files in another one. Do I require a whole different Hadoop bundle to work with other specific HDFS clusters or I could point to remote HDFS locations just overwriting those files no matter what version is used? @Niko